# Yii2 redirecting postman request to a different route in the api rest

Tags: rest, api, yii2, postman

I am accessing a route by the postman in an api made in Yii2, but the code that I insert in the action that corresponds to that route is not working. Follow the request print:

[postman-request-print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FyUB.png)

The request return was not meant to be the one in the image, because the code I put in the 'create' action was this:

```
    <?php

    namespace app\modules\api\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use app\modules\pesquisa_mercado\models\PontoDaPesquisa;

    class PesquisaPontoController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
    {
       public $modelClass = 'app\modules\pesquisa_mercado\models\PesquisaPonto';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        return $behaviors + [
            [
                'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                'except' => ['options'],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => \app\modules\api\behaviors\Verbcheck::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['GET'],
                    'create' => ['POST'],
                    'update' => ['PUT'],
                    'view' => ['GET'],
                    'delete' => ['DELETE'],
                    'finalizar-pesquisa' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['update']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {
       die("Test"); // test inserted here
    }

  }
```

That is, the return was to be 'Test'. For some reason I don't know, the route is being redirected to another place.

I also discovered that the request goes through the getLinks () method present in the PesquisaPonto model:

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\pesquisa_mercado\models;

class PesquisaPonto extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\Linkable
{
  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
   public static function tableName()
   {
      return '{{%pesquisa_ponto}}';
   }

     /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getLinks()  // the requisition also passes through here!
    {
        return [
            Link::REL_SELF => Url::to(['pesquisa-ponto/view', 'id' => $this->id], true),
            'index' => Url::to(['pesquisa-ponto'], true)
        ];
    }

}
```

Also follow the configuration of urlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => true,
            'rules' => [
                // Pontos de Pesquisa
                // api/pesquisa-ponto
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'api/pesquisa-ponto'
                    ],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                ],
             ],
          ]
```

I still haven't found the reason why Yii2 is redirecting the route and not allowing the postman to access the 'create' action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actions()` method in `yii\rest\ActiveController` looks like this

```php
 public function actions()
 {
    return [
        // ...
        'create' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\CreateAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
            'scenario' => $this->createScenario,
        ],
        // ...
    ];
}
```

In your implementation of `actions()` method you are only removing the configuration for `update` action but the configuration for `create` action is left untouched. That means that the action is run from the `yii\rest\CreateAction` not the `actionCreate()` method of the controller.

To run the action from the `PesquisaPontoController::actionCreate()` you have to unset the  configuration for the `create` action as well.

```php
public function actions()
{
     $actions = parent::actions();
     unset($actions['update'], $actions['create']);
     return $actions;
}
```